# How to set @virtual_path true in refresh() in ActionView::Template?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, render, actionview

We use `render inline` in our `rails 3.2` app:

```
<%= render inline: @erb_code, locals: {f: f} %>
```

Here `@erb_code` returns a string of `ERB code` for rendering. The problem with this inline is that the `@virtual_path` is set to false in rendering which causes error in spec in `refresh(view)` of `ActionView::Template`. Here is the error:

```
 ActionView::Template::Error:
       A template needs to have a virtual path in order to be refreshed
```

Here is the line in definition of refresh which causes error:

```
raise "A template needs to have a virtual path in order to be refreshed" unless @virtual_path
```

The full definition of the `refresh(view)` is available at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Template.html.

How to set `@virtual_path` true in rspec to avoid the spec error? But the execution of the code seems having no error. Tried assign true to `@virtual_path` in spec and it did not work.

Comment: what spec are you using?  rspec, rails test, etc?

Comment: rspec 2.0 is what we are using.

Comment: could you add the full code of the test that is failing and anything else that might be relevant?

Comment: Do you call refresh yourself (and if so, why?) or is it called by rspec internals (having more details about spec file would indeed help)

Comment: No, we did not call refresh. But somehow it shows in the error.

Comment: This strange and misleading error also appears if you feed the mailer a nil for template - such as if you have your email templates in your DB (so you can change them on the fly), but that value has not been set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to stub this refresh call in the beinning of your spec

```
ActionView::Template.any_instance.stub(:refresh)
```